# Android is it safe to use github libraries with maven

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, maven

I'm using a Gradle build system with Android Studio and have a couple of questions regarding the use of maven dependencies.

I'm using a library from github and I'm wondering if its safe to include it as a  maven dependency, or if its better to include the library into the project a different way. What happens if the owner removes the library from github? Will my app cease to work? If so then is it better to just directly include the library in my project?

To be honest I'm still a bit unclear on the details of using repositories through maven and gradle, but I'd like to know the limitations of using a library this way.

I managed to implement a library by adding a JitPack repository to my build file build.gradle, but I'm worried about the possibility of the owner removing the library rendering the app unusable. Here's the following blocks of code that I used to implement the library:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.windyzboy:CustomEditor:v1.0.1'
}
```

Does this download the files and place it in my project, or is it referencing the library somehow? If the owner of the repository removes their library, will my app still be able to use it?

Comment: That's the reason you should use libs from Maven Central cause releases will never deleted there and furthermore you should use a repository manager either with Maven or Gradle...

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I didn't realize libraries from Maven Central were unlikely to be deleted. Maybe I'll look for a different library from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Frequently Asked Questions](https://jitpack.io/docs/FAQ/)

> **What happens if a tag or repository is deleted on GitHub?**
>
> If the project was already built then JitPack will continue serving the existing artifacts. It will not rebuild the project at the new tag. In case you need to redo a release the best option is to create a new version on GitHub.

From my experience it's only possible to delete a successful build for up to seven days. But I couldn't find any official documentation about it. But I guess everyone learned from the NPM disaster.

Just use it. Many do so. It's the only channel I use for publishing my own projects so far. Your only issue is the service going down. But that's a valid concern for any other service as well.

Comment: Just read about the NPM disaster, it sounds terrible. I'm not sure I would if I would like to deal with that in the future, but it does seem unlikely to occur often. I was wondering if its possible to download the library and directly implement it into the project in android studio?

Comment: Sure it is. The JARs or AARs are just files which get downloaded. These can be imported as a module to Android Studio. Also you can use the sources directly. Just fork the project and create your own maven repo. But don't forget to apply to the License.

Comment: Oh alright, that sounds good, I appreciate the in-depth response, thank you

Comment: Gradle is a "build" system.  It downloads the libraries and packages them in your app at build time.  If a library goes away, you would lose the ability to put out a new build, but existing apps will continue to function.  You can verify this by installing an app on a device with no internet connection.  It installs just fine, indicating that all the dependencies come in the APK and are not fetched at run time.  Android is not vulnerable to the sort of thing that happened with NPM.